# Mysql Trigger to select and delete

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is this possible, can a trigger in mysql can do a select first and then based on its result do a delete?, both on the same table.

Am struggling to get it right.

There are duplicate entries in a table, i need to have a trigger which selects and then deletes.

Any ideas or thoughts will be really helpful.

Comment: Why not just write a delete statement to delete the duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete records based on your select using subqueries, you can check it here:
[link text](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)

A simple example is this:

```
DELETE FROM `tblname` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `tblname` WHERE `field` = 'must_be_deleted')
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is only one-time deletion then no need to use triggers